# Migrating the EE1.x aMember plug-in to EE2.x

Tags: integration

We're migrating a EE1.x site that uses aMember and the old 1.x aMember plug-in. New registrations are created in the EE2.x DB but log-in 'via' aMember no longer seems to work.

Did log-in change significantly between EE1.x and EE2.x? I'm guessing so but I wondered if anyone knew roughly what the differences are or happened to have updated the old EE1.x aMember ExpressionEngine plug-in to work with ExpressionEngine 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 'yes', log-in did change significantly between EE 1.x and EE2.x. For anyone running into the same issue there is an updated aMember plug-in available for EE2.x from http://www.amember.com/ (you'll need to submit a support ticket and ask for a copy).